# After running command "npm i" I started getting multiple error

Tags: npm, npm-install, spfx

I am facing this issue after I ran `npm i` command by following [THIS THREAD](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/191289/gulp-serve-error-cannot-find-module-microsoft-sp-build-web/191542#191542). Now when I am trying to install various dependency for my project, I am getting bunch of errors:

> λ npm install -g
>
> npm WARN
>   D:\ITC\node_modules\@microsoft\sp-lodash-subset\node_modules\lodash
>   is not a child of C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm
>
> npm ERR! path
>   D:\ITC\node_modules\@microsoft\sp-lodash-subset\node_modules\lodash
>
> npm ERR! code ENOENT
>
> npm ERR! errno -4058
>
> npm ERR! syscall rename
>
> npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename
>   'D:\ITC\node_modules\@microsoft\sp-lodash-subset\node_modules\lodash'
>   -> 'D:\ITC\node_modules\@microsoft\sp-lodash-subset\node_modules.lodash.DELETE'
>   npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
>
> npm ERR! enoent
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>
> npm ERR!
>   C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2017-07-26T12_26_10_273Z-debug.log

Comment: What version of npm? With some of the newer 5.x releases, there have been issues on Windows like you're seeing.  Try updating to 5.3.0 and see if the errors go away.

Comment: Additionally if you are using VSCode, it might also be part of the problem.  See: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/28593

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common issue in the new version of npm. It has been brought to their attention. I believe you can fix the issue by creating a new root directory for your project and paste everything but your node_modules folder in it. Then try npm install

Answer (score 0):

your path might be incorrect...
go to your directory and press right click with shift and select command prompt then execute your command...

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue with npm. In my situation I had the project folder on Github. Please delete the local copy of the project folder entirely. Clone the project again to local and run the `npm i` command inside the project directory.
I am assuming you are trying to install the packages installed in dependencies mentioned in `package.json`.

I used VSCode in administrator mode,
have windows 10 :build 19041.508 and
Using WSL 2.0.